# Android:errors launching new activity after method

Tags: android, class, android-intent, android-activity

I'm sorry for asking this simple question but I am quite confused. In my code I want to launch a new activity after one of my methods has been completed. So I am just going to need somebody to tell me where is the best to put `Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class); startActivity(I);`

I've tried it here but I was told that it could cause an error

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new asynctask().execute();
            Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            startActivity(I);
 }

        });
    } 
}

      class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

             private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "ResultsSet";
             private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
             private static final String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS = "Answers";
            public JSONArray json;

         @Override
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

             JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

             String URI = "http://example.com/json";

             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

             return json ;

         }{ }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                 JSONArray ResultsSet = null; {
                 try {
                     ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return;
        }}}
```

I've also tried it hear like most people suggested but I get an error underneath "MainActivity.this" that says "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope". Also I get an error underneath "startActivity(I);" and it says that I must create a whole new method called "startActivity(Intent)"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et;
    Button getanswer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new asynctask().execute();
        }

        });
    } 
}

      class asynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

             private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "ResultsSet";
             private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "Subject";
             private static final String TAG_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
             private static final String TAG_QUESTION_ANSWERS = "Answers";
            public JSONArray json;

         @Override
         protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

             JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();

             String URI = "http://rxample.com/json";

             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromURI(URI);

             return json ;

         }{ }
             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                 JSONArray ResultsSet = null; {
                 try {
                     ResultsSet = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
                 startActivity(I);
            return;
        }}}
```

can somebody tell me why Ithese errors pop up and where is the proper place to put this code.

Comment: Why did you name your second class as ListView?

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note with the first example is that the new activity will launch and run whilst the async task is running in the background. If you don't need any data returned by the task in the new activity this isn't a problem.

In the second example the problem is your reference to 'this'. You're calling that inside the class definition of the async task so the main activity is not referenced. To resolve this create a method within your main activity, something like launchNewActivity() and put the startActivity() call inside that and call it from the async task.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    launchNewActivity();
}
```

Then further up:

```
private void launchNewActivity(){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class));
}
```

Which of these is most suited to you depends on whether you need to wait for the task to finish before you start the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new asynctask().execute();
        Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
        startActivity(I);
```

Why are you calling ListView.class, This is **Android's Predefined Class**. This will take you nowhere. Create a new Activity Class then pass in to Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start ListView as activity because ListView is not activity its view :) you have to create new Activity, then define you view in xml and in onCreate method you have to setContentView(R.layout.your_view); where you can have your listView in this layout.

Then you can call

```
Intent I = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(I);
```